# Want to make sure the Username is unique

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, exception

I am trying to add a little feature to my Spring boot application where I want to username to be unique for that I am calling my get List Students method and checking if the newly added user name matches any other user username then it should give an error to the user for that I am getting an error of `antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: s` Please help me here What I am doing wrong and what should be the best practice for this.. here is my code:

**GetListOfStudents:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Student> getListOfStudent(Student studentModel) {
        List<Student> students =null;
        try {
            
            StringBuilder stringBuild = new StringBuilder("SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.id !=0 AND s.status="+Constants.StudentStatus.ACTIVE);
            if(studentModel !=null) {
                if(studentModel.getId()!=null) {
                    stringBuild.append("AND s.id =:id");
                }
                if(studentModel.getCourse()!=null) {
                    stringBuild.append("AND s.course =:course");
                }
                if(studentModel.getFirstName()!=null) {
                    stringBuild.append("AND s.firstName =:firstName");
                }
                if(studentModel.getLastName()!=null) {
                    stringBuild.append("AND s.lastName =:lastName");
                }
                if(studentModel.getEmail()!=null) {
                    stringBuild.append("AND s.email =:email");
                }
                if(studentModel.getDateOfBirth()!=null) {
                    stringBuild.append("AND s.dateOfBirth =:dateOfBirth");
                }
                if(studentModel.getStatus()!=null) {
                    stringBuild.append("AND s.status =:status");
                }
                if(studentModel.getAddedAt()!=null) {
                    stringBuild.append("AND s.addedAt =:addedAt");
                }
                if(studentModel.getUserName()!=null) {
                    stringBuild.append("AND s.userName =:userName");
                }
                if(studentModel.getPassword()!=null) {
                    stringBuild.append("AND s.password =:password");
                }
                if(studentModel.getUserType()!=null) {
                    stringBuild.append("AND s.userType =:userType");
                }
            }else {
                throw new Exception("Model is null  ===================" );
            }
            Query query = entityManage.createQuery(stringBuild.toString());
            
            if(studentModel !=null) {
                if(studentModel.getId()!=null) {
                    query.setParameter("id", studentModel.getId());
                }
                if(studentModel.getCourse()!=null) {
                    query.setParameter("course", studentModel.getCourse());
                }
                if(studentModel.getFirstName()!=null) {
                    query.setParameter("firstName", studentModel.getFirstName());
                }
                if(studentModel.getLastName()!=null) {
                    query.setParameter("lastName", studentModel.getLastName());
                }
                if(studentModel.getEmail()!=null) {
                    query.setParameter("email", studentModel.getEmail());
                }
                if(studentModel.getDateOfBirth()!=null) {
                    query.setParameter("dateOfBirth", studentModel.getDateOfBirth());
                }
                if(studentModel.getStatus()!=null) {
                    query.setParameter("status", studentModel.getStatus());
                }
                if(studentModel.getAddedAt()!=null) {
                    query.setParameter("addedAt", studentModel.getAddedAt());
                }
                if(studentModel.getUserName()!=null) {
                    query.setParameter("userName", studentModel.getUserName());
                }
                if(studentModel.getPassword()!=null) {
                    query.setParameter("password", studentModel.getPassword());
                }
                if(studentModel.getUserType()!=null) {
                    query.setParameter("userType", studentModel.getUserType());
                }
            }
            students = query.getResultList();
        }catch(Exception exe) {
            exe.printStackTrace();
        }
//      LOGGER.info("Students are : " + students);
        return students;
    }
```

**StudentController (Where I am trying to check the username)**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveStudent",method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
    public String SaveStudent(@ModelAttribute("studentFormData") Student student,BindingResult errorList) {
        List<Student> students= new ArrayList<Student>();
        try {
            students =studentService.getListOfStudent(student);
            
            for(Student sts: students ) {
                LOGGER.info("STUDENTS USER NAME :::::::::::::::::::::::" + sts.getUserName());
                if(sts.getUserName().equals(student.getUserName())) {
//                  errorList.addError(new ObjectError("error" , " Username is already taken try this user name " + utils.RandomAlphaString()));
                    LOGGER.info("USER NAME  MATCHED _______________________________________________________________________");
                    errorList.rejectValue("userName", "User name is already in use try with this username : "+ Utils.RandomAlphaString());
                }
            }
            studentService.SaveStudent(student);
            if(errorList.hasErrors()) {
                return "student/studentForm";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return "redirect:/Students/list";
    }
```

**Console:**

```
    antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: s
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:864) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:336) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:200) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:294) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: s near line 1, column 116 [SELECT s FROM com.Library.LibraryManagement.Entity.Student s WHERE s.id !=0 AND s.status=0AND s.course =:courseAND s.firstName =:firstNameAND s.lastName =:lastNameAND s.email =:emailAND s.dateOfBirth =:dateOfBirthAND s.userName =:userNameAND s.password =:passwordAND s.userType =:userType]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:734)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor109.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor109.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.createQuery(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: s near line 1, column 116 [SELECT s FROM com.Library.LibraryManagement.Entity.Student s WHERE s.id !=0 AND s.status=0AND s.course =:courseAND s.firstName =:firstNameAND s.lastName =:lastNameAND s.email =:emailAND s.dateOfBirth =:dateOfBirthAND s.userName =:userNameAND s.password =:passwordAND s.userType =:userType]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725)
    ... 128 more
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:752)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.Library.LibraryManagement.Serviceimpl.StudentServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9986e406.getListOfStudent(<generated>)
    at com.Library.LibraryManagement.Controller.StudentController.SaveStudent(StudentController.java:66)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to just query the student table for the specific username and see if it already exist rather than query for all students and compare all of them (if that is what happens)? It seems it would leave less things to cause a query syntax problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you - follow another approach to do this work.

Apply a unique constraint to a username column in your database table.

Below is an example of how you can set a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Students
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_Username UNIQUE (Username);
```

For more details, you can refer: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

While saving a new object, if an exception is thrown, then you can simply cancel/ the transaction.

Writing extra code for checking if the username exists or not is not a recommended practice. Simply use database features. It not only serves your purpose but also improves the quality of your database validations.

Comment: I do have already applied Unique constraint but I just wanted to check if the user exists or not but I think that's not the best approach anyway thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

a) `SELECT s FROM Student s` - that makes even me confused.  `select * from ...`

b) when you are doing `stringBuild.append("AND s.id =:id");` you need to allow for spaces so change to

`stringBuild.append(" AND s.id =:id ");`

and finally use a NativeQuery

```
Query query = entityManage.createNativeQuery(stringBuild.toString());
```